# Header images are not responsive

Tags: css, html

I am trying to setup a header for one of my map animations. I can place the logo and one more image on the header, more or less, but if I resize the browser the images stay with the same size.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

here is a [link](https://franpola.github.io/21_08_2018/L12_problema_22_html5.html) to see

The source code is available in [github](https://github.com/franpola/franpola.github.io/tree/master/21_08_2018) as you can see.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you give width to both images in percentage like, 40% to first and 60% to second one.. it will maintain area then..

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include  the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **within the question itself**. [mcve] A link to github is insufficient as, when it gets fixed or goes dead, will make your question and the answers pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<img src="images/logo-b.jpg" style="width:35%;">
<img src="images/wave_b.jpg" style="width:60%;">
```